# Blockchain using hyperledger Sawtooth in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, docker, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth, azure-blockchain-workbench

I have a situation which I have a feeling is a simple one, but complicated for a new block chain starter.

I would like to learn building block chain using a development environment with:
-windows 10
-hyperledger Sawtooth
-python 3.x
-visual studio code

Could anyone kindly guide on what to do. I have seen some literature that python 3 may not work with Windows 10 but I can't confirm

Comment: Please use the published docker images and setup the network, it should be the same and you will not face issues. You can also run your TP in a container and still develop on Windows machine.

Comment: Yes, I am setting up the docker images. Let me see how it goes. Thanks

Comment: @Arun I got stuck on getting publishhed docker images. Are you in a position to get in the right direction. Like a link please

Comment: Here's one of my latest example code https://github.com/arsulegai/produce-consume/blob/master/debug-sawtooth-docker-compose.yaml . For python you could check the cookiejar example as well https://github.com/danintel/sawtooth-cookiejar/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml . Note that both of these uses devmode consensus engine for development purposes.